# Windows Application Sockets vs Windows Kernel Sockets

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock2

I understand the basic about these two concepts, but I have some question for which I can't find answers on MSDN or in other related documentations.

I know that a user mode socket (WSA) creation call ends up being a CreateFile call. Is there a point somewhere in the kernel where this gets "mapped" to a Kernel Socket? Or are these two concepts completely unrelated?

That question is maybe more out of curiosity, not that the second isn't.

Why would someone choose to implement a server/client in Kernel space? If something can be done in user space why do it in kernel? Are there any real-life situation where a Kernel implementation of a client/server is a must?

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference between the sockets, but the typical reason for using sockets in kernel space is performance.  For example, Microsoft's http.sys driver accelerates performance of the IIS web server.